# Deployment of multiple .msi files

Tags: c#, deployment, process

I have around 81 .msi files that I have to install, so I decided to create an application in order to install them.  However, when I try to install one, I get an installation dialog prompt.  Is there a way to cancel all dialogs from an installation process in C# or do I need to use some kind of tool like install shield? (I'm trying to figure out how to use it.)

Right now, I'm using a dataset to store the path of the .msi and the names. In order to run the .msi I'm using `Process.Start()` inside a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing the '/quiet' parameter to the installer as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
msiexec.exe /i "path/to/installer.msi" /quiet
```

By the way, there is no reason to script this in C#.  You could script this in a simple batch file.

Comment: What about using InstallShield?, is there a way to tell installshield to execute the .msi files after they have been pass into the target computer?  I was looking the help file, but I dont know where to add code (if there is any place) for installshield in order to execute some kind of instruction related to .msi execution.

Comment: The InstallShield work I've done has been pretty straight forward but maybe this link will give you an idea: http://www.installationdeveloper.com/1954/create-bootstrapper-to-install-prerequisites-before-main-install/